# How to reuse an expression with aggregates in PostgreSQL without slowdown

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, database-performance

I frequently have queries with the same combination of aggregate functions. E.g.

```
SELECT
    my_id,
    sum(a * weight) / nullif(sum(CASE WHEN a IS NOT NULL THEN weight END), 0) AS a,
    sum(b * weight) / nullif(sum(CASE WHEN b IS NOT NULL THEN weight END), 0) AS b
FROM my_table
GROUP BY my_id
```

I would like to avoid repeating the same expressions over and over. It would be great to get the same result with a new function `weighted_avg`:

```
SELECT
    my_id,
    weighted_avg(a, weight) AS a,
    weighted_avg(b, weight) AS b
FROM my_table
GROUP BY my_id
```

The only way to do this I know of, is to use `CREATE AGGREGATE` with intermediate state and an `SFUNC` which gets called for every row. Unfortunately, this is far slower than the original query, which makes it unusable in my case.

I imagine my ideal solution would look like

```
CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION weighted_avg(x float, weight float)
RETURNS float AS $$
    SELECT sum(x * weight) / nullif(sum(CASE WHEN x IS NOT NULL THEN weight END), 0) 
$$ language SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

and be inline when executing the query. But I can't find anything similar supported by Postgres.

Comment: The use of a function is probably always going to be a little slower than just using the expressions in the original code.

Comment: I'm ok with some overhead, but the plpgsql implementation with `CREATE AGGREGATE` takes 4 times as long to execute in my case. So I would keep the original expressions, which is acceptable but I was hoping for a better solution.

Comment: Use a subquery in `FROM` to calculate the input expressions once.

Answer (score 0):

You did not show your tested aggregate function. This is how I would create it:

```
create function weighted_avg_acumm (fa float[], x float, weight float)
returns float[] as $$
    select array[
        fa[1] + x * weight,
        fa[2] + weight
    ]::float[]
$$ language sql immutable strict;

create function weighted_avg_acumm_final (fa float[])
returns float as $$
    select fa[1] / fa[2]
$$ language sql immutable strict;

create aggregate weighted_avg (x float, weight float)(
    sfunc = weighted_avg_acumm,
    finalfunc = weighted_avg_acumm_final,
    stype = float[],
    initcond = '{0,0}'
);
```

## Update

I tested and it is also much slower for me:

```
create table t (a int, weight int);
insert into t (a, weight)
select
    nullif(round(random() * 10), 0),
    trunc(random() * 10) + 1
from generate_series(1,1000000)
;

explain analyze
select weighted_avg(a, weight)
from t;
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=269425.25..269425.26 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=7933.440..7933.440 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..14425.00 rows=1000000 width=8) (actual time=0.018..241.571 rows=1000000 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.189 ms
 Execution time: 7933.508 ms

explain analyze
select 
    sum(a::numeric * weight) / 
    nullif(sum(case when a is not null then weight end), 0)
from t;
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=26925.00..26925.02 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=904.852..904.852 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..14425.00 rows=1000000 width=8) (actual time=0.010..127.264 rows=1000000 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.048 ms
 Execution time: 904.891 ms
```

Comment: It's mostly the same (some different zero and NULL handling). Unfortunately, this is about 4 times slower than the native expression.